# React - create a delete button that removes it's DOM parent and corresponding state item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a basic todo list and I am not sure how to add a delete button to each todo. In conventional DOM programming I would just add an event listener to the button and delete the parent and respective array index data. With React, I am not so sure how to structure this.

My problem is:

1. just getting it working
2. Knowing how to (and if) I should create a new component for this feature.

   ```
   var TodoItems = React.createClass({

     render: function() {
         var attr = this.props
         var todoEntries = attr.entries;



         var listItems = todoEntries.map((item) => {
             return <li key={item.key}>{item.text} <input type="button" value="DELETE"></input></li>
         });

         return (
             <ul className="theList">
               {listItems}
           </ul>
         );
     }

   });


   var TodoList = React.createClass({
       getInitialState: function() {
           return {
               items: []
           };
       },

     addItem: function(e) {
         var itemArray = this.state.items;

         itemArray.push({
             text: this._inputElement.value,
             key: Date.now()
         });

         this.setState({
             items: itemArray
         });

         this._inputElement.value = "";

         e.preventDefault();
     },

     render: function() {

         return (
             <div className="todoListMain">
             <div className="header">
               <form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
                 <input ref={(a) => this._inputElement = a}
                  placeholder="enter task">
                 </input>
                 <button type="submit">add</button>
               </form>
             </div>

             <TodoItems entries={this.state.items}/>

           </div>
         );
     }
   });




   var destination = document.querySelector("#container");

   ReactDOM.render(
     <div>
       <TodoList/>
     </div>,
     destination
   ```

   );

Comment: This is barely readable. You should definetely use ES6 classes with JSX.

Comment: The majority of JavaScript in existance is done without class syntax. If it's barely readable to you because I don't use the class keyword  then it's not my fault.

Comment: With React you only need to update the state (i.e. remove item at index from `state.items`). The component will get re-rendered and the item will disappear from the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Prerequisite understanding

I believe to start answering your question you will need to get some solid understanding of a core concept behind React.

> **Your view is a representation of your data**

Your React components *describe* how to render data to the user. **Therefore if you wish to change something within the view, you should change the data.**

In almost all cases you will not need to think about DOM manipulations. React will change your view based on changes to data.

> In conventional DOM programming I would just add an event listener to the button and delete the parent and respective array index data.

### Further reading

- [React basic theoretical concepts](https://github.com/reactjs/react-basic), specifically [transformations](https://github.com/reactjs/react-basic#transformation)

## Solution

```js
const { Component } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const defaultList = [
  'Item 1',
  'Item 2',
  'Item 3',
];

const List = (props) => (
  <ul>
    {props.items.map((item, index) => (
      <li key={index}>
        {item}
        <br />
        <button onClick={() => props.removeItem(index)}>Remove</button>
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: defaultList,
    };
  }
  
  removeItem(removeIndex) {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      ...state,
      items: this.state.items.filter((item, index) => index !== removeIndex)
    }))
  }
  
  reset() {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      ...state,
      items: defaultList,
    }))
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <List
          items={this.state.items}
          removeItem={this.removeItem.bind(this)}
        />
        <button onClick={this.reset.bind(this)}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
                   
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now that we have the prerequisite understanding in place we can walk through a solution.

Your data is a list of items, stored somewhere (could be component state or Redux store). We'll use component state in our example to keep things simple:

```
const defaultList = [
  'Item 1',
  'Item 2',
  'Item 3',
];

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: defaultList,
    };
  }
  ...
}
```

As we know the view is a representation of state, to remove an item in the view we must remove the item from the current state. To accomplish this we can define a function which will take in an argument describing which item to remove (in our case it's an index, however it could be an item object id depending on how your list is modelled). Removing it is a case of filtering out item with the index which matches the provided argument. A new state object is created and set.

```
class App extends Component {
  ...
  removeItem(removeIndex) {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      ...state,
      items: this.state.items.filter((item, index) => index !== removeIndex)
    }))
  }
  ...
}
```

This function is passed to the `List` component via its `props` and called in the `onClick` handler of each button.

```
const List = (props) => (
  <ul>
    {props.items.map((item, index) => (
      <li key={index}>
        {item}
        <br />
        <button onClick={() => props.removeItem(index)}>Remove</button>
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to create a component for the TODO that handles its deleted state itself :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './Todo.css'

class Todo extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { deleted: false }
  }

  clickFunction (event) {
    this.setState({ deleted: true })
  }

  render () {
    const classes = ['todo', this.props.className]

    return (
      {
        !this.state.deleted
        ? <li>
          {this.props.todoName}
          <button
            className={classes.join(' ')}
            onClick={this.clickFunction.bind(this)}
            value={this.props.value}
          >delete</button>
        </li>
        : null
    )
  }
}

export default Todo
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do want to know how to do it via a seperate delete button component for learning purposes.

Comment: I you want a separate component then just pass the `clickFunction` as a prop to the `delete` component (like I did with the `onClick` event, you just have to replace the `button` component by your own `DeleteTodo` one. and in `DeleteTodo` simply call `this.props.onClick`)

Comment: ....or you could use Redux. But the above comment says the way it is done, the React way.